# Schedule job in node on Every Day At 12AM only once

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using this logic

```
 var ruleServices = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();

ruleServices.hour = new schedule.Range(0,00,24);

schedule.scheduleJob(ruleServices, function(){
    var message="This is From logic 1";
    console.log(message+" on "+new Date());


});
```

this was executed after 12 AM every day but unlimited time. I want only once in a day at 12 AM and I want know about parameter of schedule.Range method ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use cron.

```
var cronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

var job = new cronJob({
  cronTime: '00 00 24 * * *',
  onTick: function() {
  // Runs everyday
  // at exactly 12:00:00 AM.

  },
  start: false,
  timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"
});

job.start();
```

This example is taken from [Node Cron Package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/cron)